# Setting an auto-incrementing field back to its original

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

I have a SQL database with a table inside called members and inside that there are some columns, one being an ID which auto-increments.

However I have done a few tests, and the auto-increment does work. But even after deleting the tests the auto-increment will not start from 0 again.

How do I make it will start back from 0 rather than carry on from about 17 or something...

EDIT:

**I have worked out the answer:**

In the "Operations" tab in phpMyAdmin there is a section called Table Options.

In there you can edit where the auto-increment continues from.

Comment: which database u are using..?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming You're using **MySQL**:

To reset the next value of *auto_increment* column, you need to use [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html) statement in the following form:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT=123
```

(Where "123" is the new next value)

Answer (score 1):

If u are using postgresql u  have following sql statement to alter sequence

```
ALTER SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq RESTART WITH 1
```

for example, if u have table called **users**, then u should do

```
ALTER SEQUENCE users_id_seq RESTART WITH 1
```

where 1 is the new sequence.